# mysqldump php command easyphp

Tags: php, mysql, easyphp

when i run the following command from the cmd box, it works fine; creates the file with my database data inside it:

```
"\Program Files\EasyPHP-5.3.8.1\mysql\bin\mysqldump" -u root -p databasename > D:\path\dumpedfile.sql
```

but then when i run this one from a php script, it makes the file, but its empty:

```
shell_exec('"\Program Files\EasyPHP-5.3.8.1\mysql\bin\mysqldump" -u root -p databasename > D:\path\dumpedfile.sql');
```

(note: i have no password setup)

what am i doing wrong?

please help
thanks

Comment: And if you try with the absolute path??

Comment: @robert, just tried full path C:\.... etc - still no joy

Comment: When you run the command via cmd box....the prompt ask for a password, or not??

Comment: yes it does, and i just hit return and then it works

Comment: But when you do the shell_exec, you see that there is no way to retrieve your password in that way...so it has to be harcoded....i'm gonna post an answer as example.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any password on your user account, you should try without the `-p` argument.

```
shell_exec('"\Program Files\EasyPHP-5.3.8.1\mysql\bin\mysqldump" -u root databasename > dumpedfile.sql');
```

Comment: @Lan, also, try to to remove the absolute path that you have on the dumped SQL so it becomes dumpedfile.sql only.

Comment: So, try to add a output parameter to the shell_exec like this ``shell_exec('"\Program Files\EasyPHP-5.3.8.1\mysql\bin\mysqldump" -u root databasename > dumpedfile.sql', $output);`` and do ``die(var_dump($output));`` after to see if we can get any clues.

Comment: just done (with exec), i get an empty array - what does that mean?

Comment: No, try it with shell_exec instead of exec since the $output of exec will only return the last line while shell_exec will instead return the full output stream in the array.

Comment: Also, make sure that you are not using the ``-p``anytime when trying out this stuff since you don't have a password.

Comment: with shell_exec it says it cant take two parameters

Comment: Hmm, running out of ideas. Try ``exec('mysqldump -u root --all-databases > test.sql');``

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. You should try ``$output = shell_exec('"\Program Files\EasyPHP-5.3.8.1\mysql\bin\mysqldump" -u root databasename > dumpedfile.sql');`` since shell_exec returns the stream... (and then dump the ``$output``) It should give some clue on what's wrong.

Comment: And with the ``--all-databases`` switch, you still get a empty sql-file?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<?php
 $User = "root";
 $Password = "mypass";
 $DatabaseName = "bcms6"
 $File = "mydump.sql";
 shell_exec("fullpath\mysqldump --allow-keywords --opt -u $User -p $Password $DatabaseName > $File");
 //Or this way
 shell_exec('"C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-5.3.9\mysql\bin\mysqldump.exe" -u root -p database > database_dump.sql'); //second way with full path.
?>
```

You can try this way too:

```
$command = 'mysqldump -u root -ppassword database > /path/database.sql';
system($command, $output);

if($output != 0) {
  echo 'Error during backup';
else {
 echo 'Database dumped';

}
```

EDITED..
The password has to be hardcoded.

Comment: thanks. just tried it but still, it makes the file but it's empty

Comment: sorry, just seen edit - what do you mean? - that there has to be a password?

Comment: So you dont have a password for you database?...user = root and empty password??

Comment: yes, but just changed it now. now i have a password and still doesnt work. just creates empty file as before

Comment: hey, sorry, dont understand last comment

Comment: Look the first piece of code...there are 2 shell_exec commands....you tried those 2 ways of shell_exec??....and, you tried too the piece of code that use system instead of shell_exec?

Comment: ah sorry. yea just tried that now. still just empty file. i think it maybe something with the easyphp testing environment- i think i'll leave it for now and have a look at it again on a real live database in the future - but thanks for all your efforts! much appreciated